# How to check the query is using the indexes in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query with where clause, I have created the index for the columns which are being used in the where clause. How can I check the query is using the indexes for these columns?

Comment: Use `explain` to see the query execution plan.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Write "explain " in front of your query. The result will tell you which indexes might be used. For example:

```
explain select * from cars;
```

You can check the column "Extra" for the information.

Comment: Thank you for answer , I did use explain and in the "key" column of the result set it showed only one column name which is in the where clause. Does it mean that it is only one index. For example : if I have two columns and indexes x and y, and my query " explain select * from test where x ="1" and y="2"", the key column shows only x

Comment: the explain shows which key is likely to be used. you can think of the tables as islands and the where clauses are bridges. a usable key makes the bridge express. as long as there's one path, your query is good